# Angular reactive form custom async validator, handle http error

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have an async validator that makes a http call to do back end validation. Need to handle http call fail and can't find any way to catch that. Any help figuring out the correct setup for that will be appreciated. Below is my current setup

The form control

```
this.email = new FormControl('', {
  validators: [
    Validators.email,
    Validators.required,
    Validators.maxLength(100)
    )
  ],
  asyncValidators: this.checkEmail.bind(this),
  updateOn: 'blur'
});
```

My async validator

```
checkEmail(control: AbstractControl) {
return this.emailService.checkEmail(control.value).map(res => {

    if (this.res.invalid) {
      return {email: true};
    }
   return null;    
});
}
```

The http call in service layer

```
 public checkEmail(email: string): Observable<any> {
    if (emailAddress) {
     return this.http.get(environment.API_URL + 'register/checkEmail?email=' + emailAddress);
   } else {
     return empty();
   }
 }
```

Comment: `checkEmail(...).catch(...)`?

Comment: And where would this catch be at? Service level? That doesn't work, expects an observable returned, validator level doesn't work either

Comment: Either, it depends whether you're using the service method in other places and for other purposes. And yes, the catch callback returns an observable, e.g. `Observable.of({ email: true })` if you consider a failing request a failure of validation (which hopefully suggests that this should be done in the validator).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I tried modifying the service call to catch at the end and I get, TS2339: Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.

Comment: I had to import catch, import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'; Thanks, led me down the right path